# Using os.system() to shutdown a computer and use pyinstaller

Tags: python, operating-system, pyinstaller, python-3.8

I have written the following code in python 3.8

```
import os

log=open('userlog.txt', 'a')
log.write(os.getlogin())
log.write('\n')
log.close()

os.system('shutdown /s /t 0')
```

It works perfectly as intended when I run it normally: it adds the username to a text file and then shuts down the computer. However, when I use pyinstaller to convert it to exe it does not work. Instead, it opens up blank command prompt windows that cannot be typed in around once a second. Any reason that this could be happening?

I am using windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling your script on Windows 10 with Python 3.6 and PyInstaller 3.6 worked for me. You might be compiling it incorrectly. For me, the following steps worked in Command Prompt (note that `%USERNAME%` is your username).

```
cd "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\path\to\script\"
pyinstaller script.py
```

The first step involves changing your current working directory to the directory containing your script. The second step is just the regular PyInstaller compilation process.

If that doesn't work check the output of the PyInstaller compilation and/or any error logs from PyInstaller. That might help you find the problem.